# Get Properties of outside object

Tags: powershell

If I have a script like this:

```
$searchfor = @("wininit","TeamViewer")
Get-Process $searchfor | % { 
    Get-nettcpconnection -OwningProcess $_.ID |
    select @{Name='Process';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName }}
}
```

how can I access the properties that `Get-Process $searchfor` returned in my `select-object`?

You can see, in the `select` expression, I need to do the `get-process` a second time, even though I feel like I already passed the information to `foreach-object`

I know i could use `foreach($x in $y)` instead of `foreach-object` but is there any way to get the properties of the outside object, when working with pipes?

Comment: save the `Get-NetTcpConnection` to a $Var. do NOT pipe it to the `Select-Object` as that will replace the 1st `Get-Process` object with the G-NTC object. at that point you should have both the saved $Var and the `Get-Process` object available for use in your `Select-Object` calculated properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters)  common parameter (PSv4+) to make each `Get-Process` output object available *inside a script block* of a *subsequent pipeline stage*:

```
$searchfor = 'wininit', 'TeamViewer'
# -PipelineVariable proc makes $proc available in script blocks later.
Get-Process $searchfor -PipelineVariable proc | % { 
  Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $_.ID |
    Select-Object @{Name='Process'; Expression={ $proc.ProcessName }}
}
```

Note:

- The variable name must be specified *without `$`* (`-PipelineVariable proc` rather than 
  <del>`-PipelineVariable $proc`</del>)
- (Sensibly) the variable is local to the pipeline (goes out of scope when the command terminates).

---

That said, in your case you could simply define an aux. variable inside the script block:

```
$searchfor = 'wininit', 'TeamViewer'
Get-Process $searchfor | % { 
  # Save the input process object in an aux. variable.
  $proc = $_
  Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $_.ID |
    Select-Object @{Name='Process'; Expression={ $proc.ProcessName }}
}
```